# Push.back into vector behavior maybe or something wrong with my for statement?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    bool Customer::checkout(Inventory* inv) {

  double total = 0;

  for( unsigned int i=0; i < _Cart.size(); i++ ) {
      total += (_Cart[i].price * _Cart[i].quant); //

  }

  if( balance < total ) {
      cout << "Checkout Failed. You do not have enough money to afford everything." 
          <<"Please go back and remove items as necessary.\n";
      return false;
  }

  else {

    unsigned int j = 0;                                          //Then, you need to add said food into the purchased vector
    for (j = 0; j < inv->_Purchases.size(); j++)    {                //When you add the food into the purchased vector, you need to look through
        if (inv->_Purchases[j].name == _Cart[j].name) {     //the entire purchased vector to see if the food is already there, 
             inv->_Purchases[j].quant += _Cart[j].quant;     //if so, increment quantity if not, just push the food into the vector
             break;

        }
    }

         if( j == inv->_Purchases.size()) {
             inv->_Purchases.push_back(_Cart[j]);
             cout << "Checkout is Complete.\n";
             return true;
        }

        _Cart.clear();

  }



    balance -= total;
    inv->interval += 1;
    inv->restock( "restock fruits.txt", 2 );
    inv->restock( "restock inventory.txt", 3);
    cout << "Checkout Complete.\n";
    return true;

}



    void Inventory::summary() {
    double total = 0;
    for( unsigned int j=0; j<_Purchases.size(); j++ ) {
      cout << "\nTotal purchases for the store are:";
      cout << "\nFood: " << _Purchases[j].name << " | Quantity: " << _Purchases[j].quant << " | Price: " << _Purchases[j].price << endl;
      total += (_Purchases[j].quant * _Purchases[j].price);
  }
  cout << "Total Purchase: " << total << endl;

    //cout the purchased vector's .name
    //cout the quant 
    //cout the price*quant
    //make a total, and cout it at the end
    }
```

Here is my main:

```
    #include "foodservice.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
      Inventory Master;
      bool flag;
      Customer Bob("Bob", 12345, 100.00 );
      Customer Joe("Joe", 56789, 50.00 );
      Customer Arjun("Arjun", 98765, 35.89 );
      Customer Randy("Randy", 54689, 30.28);
      Customer Mark("Mark", 76598, 15.18);


  Master.firststock( "inventory.txt" );
  vector<Food> temp = Master._Inv;
  cout <<"Hi, What would you like to buy today?" << endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << temp[i].name << " " << temp[i].quant << " " << temp[i].price << endl;
  }

  cout <<"\n";
  Food Apple("Apples", .99, 10);
  Food Oranges("Oranges", .99, 2);
  Food Chips("Chips", 3.00, 2);

  cout <<"\nHi Bob" << endl;
  flag = Bob.addCart(Apple, 7, &Master);
  cout <<"Bob's total purchases are Currently: \n";
  Bob.report();
  flag = Bob.addCart(Oranges, 2, &Master);
  flag = Bob.addCart(Chips, 2, &Master);
  flag = Bob.removeCart(Apple, 3, &Master);
  Bob.report();
  cout <<"Bob, ";
  flag = Bob.checkout(&Master);

  cout <<"\nHi Arjun" << endl;
  flag = Arjun.addCart(Apple, 3, &Master);
  cout <<"Arjun, ";
  Arjun.report();
  flag = Arjun.checkout(&Master);

  Master.summary();
```

when i call summary(); in main, For some reason i seem to only get apples to display for the output as in:

"Total purchases for the store are:
Food: Apples | Quantity: 7 | Price: 0.99
Total Purchase: 6.93"

But as you can see i have added apples, oranges and chips all to a cart for Bob so all three should should be displaying, but they are not. I would appreciate the help. This is still work in progress. I feel like it has something to do with

```
if( j == inv->_Purchases.size()) {
             inv->_Purchases.push_back(_Cart[j]);
             cout << "Checkout is Complete.\n";
             return true;

But i am not sure.
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your loop where you add the items already purchased. The logic is wrong.

You wrote

```
for (j = 0; j < inv->_Purchases.size(); j++)
    if (inv->_Purchases[j].name == _Cart[j].name)
...
```

but this compares `_Purchases[0]` with `_Cart[0]` and `_Purchases[1]` with `_Cart[1]` etc. What you need is two loops so you compare every `_Cart` item with every `_Purchases` item. Something like this

```
for (i = 0; i < _Cart.size(); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < inv->_Purchases.size(); j++)
    {
        if (_Cart[i].name == inv->_Purchases[j].name)
...
```

I'll leave you to fill in the rest. It will be a good exercise.

Comment: hmmm..thanks i really appreciate the help. I can see now that two loops is neccessary, but still a little stuck. Ill keep trying. And i just want to make sure if there is there anything wrong with my code regarding inv->_Purchases.push_back(_Cart[j]);??

Comment: See i also think there is something wrong with the push_back as if its the first instance of the food being bought it should be pushed back from the cart vector to the purchase vector, but it doesn't seem to be happening. Im still new to this but some feedback would be appreciated again. Thank you

Comment: It's OK, but if you use two loops like I did above you need to think carefully about which cart you are trying to push back, it's `_Cart[i]` or `_Cart[j]`? And should you put that code inside the loop or outside? It's the logic errors that are getting you at the moment.

Comment: ok i see...im going to try this out very soon. That was very helpful though. i will keep you informed and follow up once i get it to work. I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

your search loop doesn't seem quite correct:

- you use the same index to scan both _Purchases and _Cart
- you break the cycle when the first product matches the inventory

Maybe a counter for matches, to be checked when the loop is done against _Cart.size(), could work better.

Answer (score 0):

You compare same indexes on different arrays, `inv->_Purchases[ j ].name == _Cart[ j ].name` and return after adding one element, and it have problems if `_Cart.size() < inv->_Purchases.size()` ( buffer overflow ) or `_Cart.size() == 0` ( dereferencing null pointer ).

So change this:

```
{
    unsigned int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < inv->_Purchases.size(); j++)
    {
        if (inv->_Purchases[j].name == _Cart[j].name)
        {
            inv->_Purchases[j].quant += _Cart[j].quant;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( j == inv->_Purchases.size() )
    {
        inv->_Purchases.push_back( _Cart[j] );
        cout << "Checkout is Complete.\n";
        return true;
    }
    _Cart.clear();
}
```

into this:

```
{
    unsigned i, PurchasesBefore = inv->_Purchases.size();
    while( !_Cart.empty() )
    {
        for( i = 0; i != inv->_Purchases.size(); ++i )
        {
            if( inv->_Purchases[i].name == _Cart.back().name )
            {
                inv->_Purchases[i].quant += _Cart.back().quant;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( i == inv->_Purchases.size() )
            inv->_Purchases.push_back( _Cart.back() );
        _Cart.pop_back();
    }
    if( PurchasesBefore != inv->_Purchases.size() )
    {
        cout << "Checkout is Complete.\n";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: I am not sure about this code:

```
balance -= total;
inv->interval += 1;
inv->restock( "restock fruits.txt", 2 );
inv->restock( "restock inventory.txt", 3);
cout << "Checkout Complete.\n";
return true;
```

Comment: Would be nice to add an explanation of what's wrong, in addition to fixing the code